# How to let withTimeoutOrNull return null but finish code in the block

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I need my code to run a block and return value after 1 second in case timeout but let it finish the job.
I managed to implement something that works but IDE suggest replacing `async` with `withContext(DefaultDispatcher)` but it's not working the same.

So my question is how to make it work without IDE warnings. I am new to Kotlin Coroutines so I might be missing something here.

```
@Test
fun how_timeout_with_null_works() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        println("Start test")
        val result = withTimeoutOrNull(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) {
            async { doSomeHardWork() }.await()
        }
        println("End test $result")
    }
    println("Time $time")
    delay(3000)
}

private suspend fun doSomeHardWork(): String {
    println("start hard work")
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    print("end hard work")
    return "[hard work done]"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IDE gives a warning in this case because `async(ctx) { ... }.await()` is usually a mistake and `withContext(ctx) { ... }` usually better reflects the original intent of the author of the code.

In case of your code, your intent is different. Your intent is to *await* for 1 second, without constraining your `doSomeHardWork` code. However, the *structure* of your code does not reflect your intent. You've wrapped the whole block into `withTimeout` and put `doSomeHardWork` inside of it, while your intent was only to do a time-limited *wait* for it. So, if you rewrite your code in the way where the structure of your code matches your intent, it will work without any warnings:

```
val work = async { doSomeHardWork() } // start work
val result = withTimeoutOrNull(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) { work.await() } // wait with timeout
```

If you happen to need this pattern of code more than once, then you can define yourself a handy extension:

```
suspend fun <T> Deferred<T>.awaitWithTimeout(time: Long, unit: TimeUnit): T? =
    withTimeoutOrNull(time, unit) { await() }
```

And then write even nicer code that reflects your intent:

```
val result = async { doSomeHardWork() }.awaitWithTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Be careful, though. These coroutines that you start with `async` will continue running after the wait had timed out. This can easily lead to resource leaks, unless you take steps to limit the number of those concurrently running background jobs.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. `withTimeoutOrNull` returns `Unit` immediately without actually suspending. 
So if I check `if (result == null) {}` this will always be `false` and will work like the Timeout is now valid.